# Load DDL into schema

Tags: sql-server

I have a tool that generates a DDL script

```
create table ATTRIBUTE_VALUE (
    id int identity not null,
    version int null,
);

create table BADGE (
    id int identity not null,
    version int null,
    cms_ci_ref varchar(255) not null unique,
    primary key (id)
);

/* more tables */
```

Notice that the table names are not prefixed by the schema name - I have no control over this. I want to create these tables in `myschema`, and am hoping there's some command I can execute before loading this script that will set the current schema to `myschema`, so that I can then use the DDL without modification.

Something like....

```
use myschema;
load ddl;
```

Does SQL Server provide a command like this?

Comment: How will you be executing these scripts?

Comment: They will be executed by Maven (specifically the sql-maven-plugin) when building my app

Comment: Out of interest, what's the tool that generates the DDL?

Comment: @David the DDL is generated by hbm2ddl, a tool provided by Hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [if using a SQL Server login.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)

```
ALTER USER ... WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = myschema
```

Notes from my link:

> DEFAULT_SCHEMA cannot be specified for a user who is mapped to a Windows group,
>
> The value of DEFAULT_SCHEMA is ignored if the user is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role. All members of the sysadmin fixed server role have a default schema of dbo.